# Printing curried function doesn't show the captured parameter

Tags: javascript, currying

If I define a curried function like this:

```
const gt = x => y => y > x
```

I would expect `gt(5)` returns `y => y > 5`

but `gt(5)` (or `gt(5).toString()`) returns `y => y > x`

How do I get the captured parameter?

Comment: Useful article: https://medium.com/@drboolean/debugging-functional-7deb4688a08c

Answer (score 1):

> I would expect gt(5) returns y => y > 5

That isn't how JavaScript works. The code of the function returned by `gt(5)` is `y => y > x`, it's just that that code executes in an environment where the identifer `x` resolves to a binding that has the value `5` because it's a *closure* over that environment. `toString` on functions returns a string version of the source code of the function (or a function declaration around the `[ native code ]`) ([spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.tostring)), so you still see `y => y > x`. The string returned by `toString` doesn't include the environment in which that code runs.

See also:

- [*How do JavaScript's closures work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) - here on SO
- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) - on my old anemic blog (uses some outdated terminology, I should probably fix that)

---

As [@VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) points out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66515278/printing-curried-function-doesnt-show-the-captured-parameter#comment117585892_66515352), you can override the default `toString` on a function to give it the behavior you want. If you don't mind duplication (which almost inevitably leads to maintenance issues):

```js
const gt = x => {
    const fn = y => y > x;
    fn.toString = () => `y => y > ${x}`;
    return fn;
};
console.log(String(gt(5)));
```

...or if you want to define `toString` with the same enumerability, etc., as the version on the prototype:

```
Object.defineProperty(fn, "toString", {
    value: () => `y => y > ${x}`,
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
});
```

Doing that in the general case requires a proper JavaScript parser to do the substitution.

Comment: However, it's possible to override the `.toString()` of the curried function and provide a more useful version.

Comment: @VLAZ - Quite true! I'm speaking of the standard behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to just print a variable captured in a closure, however there is a workaround for curry. I will be referring to Brian Lonsdorf's article on Medium [Debugging Functional](https://medium.com/@drboolean/debugging-functional-7deb4688a08c) which goes into more details about curry and compose. I heartily recommend reading the article itself, as I will only use the essentials.

Brian Lonsdorf proposes a custom implementation of a general `curry` function. The original version is taken from [an article by Erin Swenson-Healy](https://blog.carbonfive.com/gettin-freaky-functional-wcurried-javascript/).

Here is the modified version:

```js
function fToString(f) {
  return f.name ? f.name : `(${f.toString()})`;
}

function curry(fx) {
  var arity = fx.length;

  function f1() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    if (args.length >= arity) return fx.apply(null, args);

    function f2() {
      return f1.apply(null, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0))); 
    }

    f2.toString = function() {
      return fToString(fx)+'('+args.join(', ')+')';
    }
    return f2;
  };

  f1.toString = function() { return fToString(fx); }
  return f1;
}

const gt = curry((x, y) => y > x);
const sum3 = curry((x, y, z) => x + y + z);
const ltUncurried = (x, y) => y < x;

const lt = curry(ltUncurried);

console.log(gt(1));      // ((x, y) => y > x)(1)
console.log(sum3(1));    // ((x, y, z) => x + y + z)(1)
console.log(sum3(1, 2)); // ((x, y, z) => x + y + z)(1, 2)
console.log(sum3(1)(2)); // ((x, y, z) => x + y + z)(1, 2)

console.log(lt(1));      // ltUncurried(1)
```

(I have modified `fToString()` to include brackets around `f.toString()` for better readability)

This is quite flexible as it allows currying any function but also provides better logging of said function. The `toString` implementation can be modified if required for whatever you deem are the most important details.

Answer (score 0):

```
const gt = x => y => y > x
gt(1);
```

If you had pass only 1 argument like **gt(1)** and if you Check in console, **x = 1, y is not available at this time**. So the execution context (**call stack**) will show only the x argument and for the **gt()** method it will only show the code (y > x).

And here below gives us a hint that **gt(1) will first bind x to 1**, and **return a new function f(y) = y > x = y > 1**

You didn't second pass second argument, It means now the function f(y) = 1 + y is executed, and this time, it will check for the y where y is not available at that time. And the **argument x’s value 1 is still preserved in the context via Closure**.

It's look like same as below closure function :-

```
function add(x) {
    return function (y) {
        return y > x
    }
}

var d = add(1)(2); ===>>>> true
```